# Update Checkbox Formula Field - Case?

Tags: formula

I am trying to make a checkbox formula field on a custom object using a CASE function to set the value. There are specific entries in a text field that I would like to set the new checkbox to true, and the rest false. It seems the CASE function only allows text output. Is there a way to do this using CASE?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, by returning 1 or 0 (returning numbers is fine, it's just booleans that are an issue)
then checking equality to 1

e.g.

```
CASE(
    Some_Field__c,
    'value 1', 1,
    'value 2', 1,
    'value 3', 1,
    ...
    'value n', 1,
    /* default case if none of the values match */
    0
) == 1
```